# How to expose external IP of one Node Kubernetes Ingress Service into the internet

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress, metallb

I installed a one node Kubernetes with `kubeadm`. This is on a `vServer` "bare metal" with dedicated external static IP.

With these components/settings:

- calico (default settings)
- MetalLB (Layer 2 config with address range `192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250`)
- Traefik (default settings)

Now a traefik service is exposed as an "external IP" but the IP is `192.168.1.240`. This is external from k8s point of view but how do I expose the ingress service to the internet?

I do not want to set up an additional external load balancer. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

metalLB is not needed at all. When you install traefik add this value file (as `traefik.yaml` in this case):

```
service:
  externalIPs:
    - <your_external_static_ip_here_without_the_brackets>
```

and then install it like this: `helm install --values=./traefik.yaml traefik traefik/traefik -n traefik --create-namespace`